# Compare Two Bits to One Bit

Tags: sql

I have a query where I need to pull in all base and seasonal positions at a store, if the position is valid:

```
Select ojr.StoreNumber, ojr.Seasonal, ojr.JobType
FROM OJR ojr
Inner Join OJR_StoreInfo si on ojr.StoreNumber = si.Storenumber AND 
  CASE WHEN si.Seasonal-Barista = 1 Then 1 WHEN si.Base-Barista = 1 
  Then 0 ELSE NULL END = ojr.Seasonal
```

The table structures are like so:

**OJR**

```
ID  StoreNumber  Seasonal  JobType
___________________________________
1  71001        0         Barista
2  71001        1         Barista
3  71002        0         Barista
4  71002        0         Sales
```

**StoreInfo**

```
StoreNumber  Base-Barista  Seasonal-Barista  Base-Sales  Seasonal-Sales
_______________________________________________________________________
71001        1             1                 1           0
71002        0             1                 1           1
71003        0             0                 0           0
```

So the issue is that when I run the above query, ID 1 does not come in, because Storeinfo takes in both Seasonal AND base baristas, but the INNER JOIN determines that the I am looking for seasonal - because it hits the first WHEN and proceeds to "END" and never reaches the 2nd WHEN. Is there another way I can get around this? I think a subquery will be needed for the inner join, but I just can't figure it out yet.

Desired Output:

```
StoreNumber  Seasonal  JobType
__________________________________
71001        0         Barista
71001        1         Barista
71002        0         Sales
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please post your desired output and what you actually get. I _think_ I understand what you want, but then not quite. Note that you can nest `CASE` staments, as in `CASE WHEN <blah> THEN CASE ... END END`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Editted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-formulate join criteria without `case` expression, like this:

```
SELECT
    ojr.StoreNumber
,   ojr.Seasonal
,   ojr.JobType
FROM OJR ojr
INNER JOIN OJR_StoreInfo si
   ON ojr.StoreNumber = si.Storenumber
 AND ((si.Seasonal-Barista = 1 AND ojr.Seasonal=1) OR (si.Base-Barista = 1 AND ojr.Seasonal=0))
```

The above condition eliminates the need to come up with a number that matches `ojr.Seasonal`, replacing it with two separate logical conditions.